# Bootstrap how to make responsive / collapse rows?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

i'm new to Twitter Bootstrap and can't figure this out.. I have the following code. How do I actually collapse the rows to fall underneath each other when I change the screen width (i.e. to mobile width). At the moment it just squashes the rows together and does not drop the rows beneath each other. Any code to help would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Bootstrap test</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

</head>

<body>
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span4" style="overflow:auto">Column 1</div>
        <div class="span4">Column 2</div>
    <div class="span4">Column 3</div>
    </div>

<div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span3">Column 1</div>
        <div class="span3">Column 2</div>
    <div class="span3">Column 3</div>
    <div class="span3">Column 4</div>
    </div>

<div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">Column 1</div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is achieved by styling the [Media Queries](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2012/04/23/responsive-web-design-layouts-and-media-queries/) in your CSS.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {}
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {}
```

Style the elements within these css snippets to get the desired effect.

For example; to drop elements underneath eachother in let's say.. mobile view:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  #divid {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
  float: left;
  position: relative; }
  background: black; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the Order of your stylesheet imports and that they exist in the folders.
The responsive one should be imported after the main file

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```